# Understanding a basic implementation of Redux | how is prevState used?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, redux, react-redux

I'm looking at this example of a super basic implementation of redux from [this article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367#.5201dku9c). I understand it except where dispatch uses `prevState`. First off where does this function get prevState? How is this related to the actually state that counter needs? Does it implicitly set another value in the state called prevState? I'm just having a hard time understanding how the state actually gets passed to dispatch and then counter through prevState. I think this is probably a functional programming idea that I just haven't grasped yet. Thanks for helping me understand!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const counter = (state = { value: 0 }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return { value: state.value + 1 };
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return { value: state.value - 1 };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

class Counter extends Component {
  state = counter(undefined, {});
  
  dispatch(action) {
    this.setState(prevState => counter(prevState, action));
  }

  increment = () => {
    this.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' });
  };

  decrement = () => {
    this.dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' });
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.value}
        <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**React.Component.prototype.setState**

Well react's [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) method is responsible for `prevState` here – *not* redux, just to be clear.

Let's look at how `setState` can be used. We have **3** options ...

1. `setState(nextState)` - just pass the next state and React will update the components `state` accordingly
2. `setState(nextState, callback)` – optionally specify a callback that is called once the component is re-rendered – a React component will re-render whenever `state` is updated – Note: React docs generally recommend to use [`componentDidUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle method for this instead.
3. `setState((prevState, props) => nextState)` – call with a function that conveniently binds `prevState` and `props` identifiers for us to manually update our state. It's expected that the function we provide returns the next state

So you have this

```
this.setState(prevState => counter(prevState, action));
```

If it's not obvious, the code example you've provided is using **#3**. So, the first parameter `prevState` will be provided by React which is the *current* state of the component. The second parameter `props` is not used here, so we'll just ignore it (tho the general idea is you could use props to update your state if relevant).

---

**What is `prevState`?**

What exactly is `prevState`? Well we established that it's the current state of your component, which we initialized earlier in the Counter as

```
state = counter(undefined, {});
// => { value: 0 }
```

So when we dispatch an `INCREMENT` we will get something along the lines of

```
this.setState(prevState => counter({value: 0}, {type: 'INCREMENT'})
```

In which case `counter` (reducer) will return

```
{value: 1}
```

This return value is what will be the *next* state of the Component

---

**Repeated applications of `setState`**

Of course if we were to `INCREMENT` again, we'd have something like

```
this.setState(prevState => counter({value: 1}, {type: 'INCREMENT'})
```

Where `counter` would return

```
{value: 2}
```

which becomes the next state of the Component

and so on..

---

***"Where is line between React and Redux?"***

To start, the React-specific code is the `import` and the `Counter` class which extends `Component`.

*"But what is the other code (`counter`) then?"*

One of the coolest things about redux is its state of *nothingness* – Redux only exists in this code example as a pattern. There's no `import` which uses the `redux` or `react-redux`. Redux is used here more as an implementation of the idea/philosophy of redux – which is built around this idea of unidirectional flow of data and composable reducers.

*"What is a reducer?"*

A reducer is simply a function which, when applied to a state and an action, returns a *new* state.

Of course the `redux` library includes some helpful utilities which make it easier to implement Redux's patterns within your application – but really, they're all incredibly simple functions. In fact, the creator of Redux, Dan Abramov, has an *awesome* (FREE) series on egghead, [Getting Started with Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) which shows you exactly how Redux works, piece by piece. In my opinion, it is one of the best coding video series ever created, on *any* topic.

Comment: Oh interesting, thanks for this. I didn't realize that you have two options for setState - object or function. I've only ever used the object to set the new state. Is it possible to use a callback with the function as well, making that 4 options?

Comment: Well I linked to the docs and outline the **3** options available in my answer. `setState` has **3** options for use; not 2 or 4.

Comment: ok so it looks like the callback can only pair with the object in the docs. But it doesn't give an example of using that callback or why you'd need a callback.

Comment: @AnnaGarcia correct, `setState(nextState, callback)` is the only option that uses a *callback*, but not the only option that accepts a *function*. The third option `setState((prevState, props) => nextState)` also accepts a *function* but performs a synchronous, atomic update.

Comment: @AnnaGarcia you have to read a little further in the docs if you want them to explain the `setState(nextState, callback)` usage – the callback is called when the component has finished re-rendering. I've updated my answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

`prevState` in this case is an actual, current state. It's not traveling back in time, it simply returns your current state, which is going to be used in order to build a new one - because in Redux and React's concept, the state is `immutable`, that means it never gets modified - when you dispatch new action and handle it with your reducer - you're creating completely new object (state).

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the Class *Counter* extends from React's *Component* type. Because of this it will inherit a bunch of properties and methods, one of which is *setState*.

We can see from the [React documentation for setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) that it takes two arguments:

```
setState(nextState, callback)
```

But in the fine print it says this: ***"The first argument can be an object (containing zero or more keys to update) or a function (of state and props) that returns an object containing keys to update."***

In the case here, we are only passing one argument, so we must be using it with the first argument being a function that returns an object of keys to update.

If we take another look at the original code where setState is used:

```
this.setState(prevState => counter(prevState, action));
```

It might be a little easier to read and understand if we wrote this in es5 JavaScript syntax:

```
this.setState(
  function cb(prevstate) {
    return counter(prevstate, action)
  })
```

So in this case "prevState" is an argument to an anonymous function. In theory, it could be named anything and as long as you use the same name to refer to it inside on the function body everything will be fine. However, it seems like a pretty standard thing to name it "prevState" (that's what the React docs use).

If we look at this as purely JavaScript the *prevState* that you are passing into this function should be undefined.

Therefore, firing the INCREMENT action multiple times should result in your state value always being 1 since the counter function will always use the default value:

```
state = { value: 0 }
```

I would think the dispatch function should look like to this:

```
dispatch(action) {
    this.setState(counter(this.state, action));
}
```

**UPDATE**

[This link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) may explain it better, but indeed if you use a function as the first argument for setState then ***this function will take the current state as its argument***, and so that is how *prevState* gets its value.

Comment: The term "callback" as a generic word to describe a function that gets passed to another function is very dangerous here. The majority of people use "callback" to describe an asynchronous callback in which case the `return` value is completely discarded. But in this case, it's *synchronous* and the `return` value is absolutely required.

Comment: interesting. The last part you wrote - the statevalue will always be 1. If the prevState is actually the current state, wouldn't this.setState(counter(this.state, action)); or this.setState(counter(prevState, action)); be the same thing? So then in the counter reducer the value will always grow?

Comment: I didn't realize that React automatically "fills in" the first argument of your function with the current state. So "prevState" is not null, it's the current state. It's called "prevState" because you have an action that you want to handle and transform your state into a new current state.

Comment: Yea I think that's what we are saying here, right? React "fills in" prevState with the actual state but we just call it prevState?

Comment: Yes, React fills in the variable "prevState" with the current state. It's all about your perspective in time. If you look at it as if "setState" was just called an instant ago then *prevState* was the old state before it was modified by the action and the new current state is a new object created from *prevState* and then modified in some way from the action.